# Как можно оптимизировать код, что бы он выполнялся быстрее?

Tags: java, олимпиада

Есть код, для задания он выполняется долго, как его можно оптимизировать?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void input(int[] array, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int[] array_search = new int[m];

        input(array, n);
        input(array_search, m);

        for (int search = 0; search < m; ++search)
        {
            int value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                if (array[i] == array_search[search])
                    value = i + 1;
            }
            array_search[search] = value;
        }

        for (int i : array_search)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Задача:
[image: Задача]

Comment: Прелдагаете догадаться, что за задачу ваш код решает?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Answer (score 2):

Из условия *массив чисел, отсортированных в неубывающем порядке* имеем - массив отсортирован. К сортированному массиву можно применить [бинарный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) временная сложность которого `O(log n)`. Временная сложность вашего текущего алгоритма `O(n)`. Единственное, не забудьте учесть условие "про правый индекс".

Попробуйте реализовать бинарный поиск сами, но если что, можно посмотреть реализацию [тут](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Java/tree/master/Searches)

Comment: сложность не `O(n)` а скорее `O(n*m)`

Comment: Но лучше используйте уже готовую реализацию бинарного поиска из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @belo4ya спасибо за ваш совет, попробовал. Из всех попыток можно сказать, что сервер криво проверяет программу, либо не вывозит)

Comment: @Bakuard, подскажите пожалуйста, в каком пакете я могу найти готовую реализацию бинарного поиска?

Comment: Класс java.util.Collections имеет метод binarySearch для реализаций List. Класс java.util.Arrays имеет метод binarySearch перегруженный для любых типов массивов.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете пробежать по массиву и построить словарь, где ключ - число, значение - его правый индекс. Сложность алгоритма при этом становится линейная.

Пример

```
    int[] array = new int[3];
    int[] array_search = new int[3];

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 3;
    array[2] = 5;

    array_search[0] = 1;
    array_search[1] = 5;
    array_search[2] = 7;


    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (!map.containsKey(array[i]))
            map.put(array[i], i);

    for (int i = 0; i < array_search.length; i++)
        if (map.containsKey(array_search[i]))
            System.out.println(map.get(array_search[i]) + 1);
        else
            System.out.println("0");
```

Comment: построение словаря можно с вводом данных совместить

Comment: @Grundy можно :)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за помощь, но судя из всех попыток сервер криво проверяет программу, либо просто не вывозит) Ошибка времени выполнения, не пропускает по времени.

Comment: @Roven так вы покажите, какой конкретно код не пропускает. А то может вы скопировали не так или еще что.